# Send image in value html

Tags: html

I am trying to mess with a message people get on their phones on this website and I want to send a image
I want to put a image in the value part of the code (Sorry if I'm using incorrect terms I am fairly new to html)

`<input id="text" class="text" value="I want the image here" placeholder="Type your message here" autofocus="">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only link to the image in the text input so the value will be the location of the image.

```
<input type="text" value="www.website.com/image.gif">
```

If you want them to type into the text field the value will change to whatever they type into the field.

You also get an actual image input type

```
 <input type="image" src="img.gif" alt="image">
```

Comment: Thank you but one more question is there a way I can send a image to the text variable (or whatever it is called)?

Comment: You can use php to do that. <input type="hidden" name="fooled_image" value="www.website.com/image.gif"> then you have your normal text input where they type the message  <input type="text" name="message">. You can then send both variables with php form $_POST .  See this link on how to - https://html.form.guide/php-form/php-form-variables/

Comment: Yes. You can send the path of the image. So to display the image it would look like <img src='$image' alt='Alt text'>